# WriteFile sometimes returns error code 6

Tags: c#, windows

Following is the code snippet:

CreateFile code:

```
m_RunFileHandle = CreateFile(strRunFullPath,
                             EFileAccess.GenericWrite,
                             EFileShare.None,
                             IntPtr.Zero, 
                             ECreationDisposition.CreateAlways,
                             EFileAttributes.Write_Through | EFileAttributes.NoBuffering,
                             IntPtr.Zero);
```

WriteFile code:

```
WriteFile(m_RunFileHandle, NewFramePixelData, nDataSize, out nBytesWritten, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Query: Very rarely WritrFile method returns the Error code 6.

Comment: ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) looks like reasonable error if you randomly close file (or something else happens with handle...). Without [MCVE] it would be very hard to say anything.

Comment: One common cause is failing to check whether CreateFile succeeded or failed.

Answer (score -1):

A pointer to an OVERLAPPED structure is required if you use the file in FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED mode otherwise ensure CreateFile is not called multiple times without closing the handle.

Check whether CreateFile is called more than once (without closing the previously created handle) before making the call "WriteFile". In this case system can return error 6.

Comment: Only if you don't check for errors properly.  The error you're talking about happens when CreateFile is called - only if you ignore that error will WriteFile fail with error code 6.

Answer (score -2):

solvent is:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool WriteFile(
    IntPtr hFile,
    byte[] lpBuffer,
    UInt32 nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
    ref UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
    ref DriverEntity.OVERLAPPED lpOverlapped);
```

modify to:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool WriteFile(
    IntPtr hFile,
    byte[] lpBuffer,
    UInt32 nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
    ref UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
    IntPtr lpOverlapped);
```

use:

```
DriverDAL.WriteFile(
    hDevice,
    writeBuffer,
    (uint)writeBuffer.Length,
    ref RealityWriteCount,
    IntPtr.Zero);
```